# How clear GridView in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I doing a web page in asp.net and in a module have select a Excel archive with `FileUpLoad` and click in a button import. Hitherto I'm fine. But in the moment than I want select other Excel archive and click in the button import, don't clear the `GridView` and show error. I attempt with this because I see in other questions similar to this.

With this I load the Grid

```
Conn = string.Format(Conn, DireccionArchivo, MostrarHDR);
OleDbConnection ConnExcel = new OleDbConnection(Conn);
OleDbCommand CmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter Oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
CmdExcel.Connection = ConnExcel;

ConnExcel.Open();
CmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From ["Page1$"]";
Oda.SelectCommand = CmdExcel;
Oda.Fill(Dt);
ConnExcel.Close();

grdResultados.Caption =  Path.GetFileName(DireccionArchivo);
grdResultados.DataSource = Dt;
grdResultados.DataBind();
```

And with this I want to clear the `GridView` and last y called of new the method of load the `GridView`

```
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
ds = null;
grdResultados.DataSource = ds;
grdResultados.DataBind();
```

The error than show me is in the `grdResultados.DataBind();` when called the second time.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: A field or property with name 'Name' was not found in the selected data source. Possible causes of this error may be the following: an incorrect or case-insensitive spelling of the grid column name; assigning a wrong or not properly initialized data source to the grid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I resolved the problem, in the moment than clear the GridView with

```
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
ds = null;
grdResultados.DataSource = ds;
grdResultados.DataBind();
```

this clear the GridView but dont clear the names of columns, and this was the error, also have to clean the names of the columns. To remove the columns:

```
for (int i = 0; grdResultados.Columns.Count > i; )
{
    grdResultados.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

and in the method of load th GridView must be generate the columns automatically with this property:

```
grdResultados.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

I leave this in case anyone else has the same problem

Comment: You don't need to iterate through the Columns. Instead just perform a grdResultados.Columns.Clear(); command.

Answer (score 32):

Just use null value:

```
grdResultados.DataSource = null;
grdResultados.DataBind();
```

Comment: sounds like you are getting the error even before the null binding ? match the name field on your datasource and gridview

Comment: i get the error when i called the method of load the gridview for second time in : `grdResultados.DataBind();`

Comment: This worked exactly for me. Other solutions I've found have said to use 'Gridview.Rows.Clear();
Gridview.Refresh();' 
But that must be deprecated because I don't even have the Clear option. Setting datasource to null and then rebinding will clear out everything in the grid. As others mentioned, reset the datasource and bind again for additional content.

Comment: I get this when selecting another page: "The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled."

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
grdResultados.DataSource = null;
```

or

```
grdResultados.Rows.Clear();
```

then rebind the gridview

Comment: I do not work with those, neither with `grdResultados.Columns.Clear`

Comment: wich error did you get? if the problem is the gridview to clear the solution is this

Comment: this is the error: A field or property with name 'Name' was not found in the selected data source. Possible causes of this error may be the following: an incorrect or case-insensitive spelling of the grid column name; assigning a wrong or not properly initialized data source to the grid.

Comment: has your datasource the Name property?

Comment: yes i have, the error where show me is in: `grdResultados.DataBind();`

Comment: has your new datasource the property Name? try setting that property to allow null values in configuration

Answer (score 2):

```
int gvHasRows = grdResultados.Rows.Count;
if (gvHasRows > 0)
{
    grdResultados.Columns.Clear();
    grdResultados.DataBind();
}
```

First check that there is data in the Gridview before trying to clear.
Rows has no Clear function.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Session clear the session Example:

```
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
ds = null;
GV.DataSource = ds;
GV.DataBind();

for (int i = 0; GV.Columns.Count > i; )
{
    GV.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
}

ViewState["CurrentData"] = null;
```

Comment: Tried this and obtained this result when selecting a page: "The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled."

Answer (score 0):

Make an empty data table with just your column names and re bind

Comment: i have the error because i dont clear the names of the columns. This: `grdResultados.DataSource = null` dont clear the names of the columns

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If dataset IsNot Nothing AndAlso dataset.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
grid.DataSource = dataset
grid.DataBind()
Else
grid.DataSource = Nothing
grid.DataBind()

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [answer] a question.  This question was asked over over 6 years ago and has an accepted answer.  Please take a look at some of the unanswered questions here.... [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0) or search for tags that relate to your specific skills here [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a XAML defined Grid, use this instead:

```
GridView1.Children.Clear();
GridView1.RowDefinitions.Clear();
GridView1.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
```